# Longtabu multi-row glitch

Tags: multirow, tabu

After a long fight against \multicolumn and \rowcolor, I am facing a strange glitch with \multicolumn on my yet very simple array. Could somebody help me ?

```
\taburowcolors[2]{white .. black!10}
\sffamily\footnotesize
\tabulinesep=6pt

\begin{longtabu}{|>{\cellcolor{gray}\color{white}}r|>{\cellcolor{gray}\color{white}}r|X[cm]|X[cm]|X[cm]|X[cm]|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{ \columncolor{gray}}c|}{\strut} & \cellcolor{gray}\color{white}A & \cellcolor{gray}\color{white}B & \cellcolor{gray}\color{white}C & \cellcolor{gray}\cellcolor{gray}\color{white}D\\
    \hline
    % Content Start
    \multirow{2}{*}{CTRL} & LB         & Oui        &            &            & Non \\
                          & HA         & Non        & Oui        & Oui        &  \\
    % Content End
    \hline
\end{longtabu}
```

[image: Generated PDF]

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content in the multi row is put first and the first cell in the second row is painted later. This results in the lower part of the content (that is put over this first cell) going below. To avoid this, delay putting the contents. This is done by adding `\multirow{-2}{*}{CTRL}` in the second row. Notw the `-2` which asks `multirow` to span backwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \taburowcolors[2]{white .. black!10}
\sffamily\footnotesize
\tabulinesep=6pt

\begin{longtabu}{|>{\cellcolor{gray}\color{white}}r|>{\cellcolor{gray}\color{white}}r|X[cm]|X[cm]|X[cm]|X[cm]|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{ \columncolor{gray}}c|}{\strut} & \cellcolor{gray}\color{white}A & \cellcolor{gray}\color{white}B & \cellcolor{gray}\color{white}C & \cellcolor{gray}\cellcolor{gray}\color{white}D\\
    \hline
    % Content Start
                      & LB         & Oui        &            &            & Non \\
     \multirow{-2}{*}{CTRL}     & HA         & Non        & Oui        & Oui        &  \\
    % Content End
    \hline
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow really ! Thanks <3 You are so pro. Have a nice day !